# $\mu(f(E))$ when $|f'(x)| \leq M$

Tags: real-analysis

I would love some help with the following question:

> Let $f$, a differentiable function in $[0, 1]$, such that $|f'(x)|
> > \leq M$ for every $x \in [0,1]$. Prove that for every Lebesgue
>   measurable set, $E \subset [0,1]$, $f(E)$ is Lebesgue measurable, and
>   $\mu(f(E)) \leq M\times\mu(E)$.

I know how to prove that $f(E)$ is measurable by proving for compact sets, $F_{\sigma}$ sets, sets with $\mu(E) = 0$, and then any Lebesgue measurable set. The second part, I'm having trouble with:

**First question:** It seems to me like the proof that $\mu(f(E)) \leq M\times\mu(E)$ should be follow the same lines above (so that I can prove both requirements together), but I can't think of a way to do it. Ideas?

**Second question:** I thought about the following proof, but I'm not sure it's correct:

1. Choose an open set, $G$, such that $E \subset G$ and $\mu(G) \leq \mu(E) + \epsilon$
2. Use Egorov's Theorem to get subsets of $G$: $G_n$, such that $\mu(G\setminus G_n) < \frac{1}{n}$ and
   $$
   f'_n := \frac{f(x + 1/n) - f(x)}{1/n}
   $$
   converges uniformly to $f'$ on $G_n$.
3. Divide $G_n$ to intervals shorter than the $\delta $ we got from uniform convergence, and show $\mu(f(G_n)) \leq M\times\mu(G_n)$
4. WLG, $G_n$ is non decreasing and $G =  \lim_{ n \to \infty }G_n$, hence $f(G) = \lim_{ n \to \infty }f(G_n)$, and $\mu(f(G)) = \lim_{ n \to \infty }\mu(f(G_n)) \leq \lim_{ n \to \infty }M\times(\mu(G) - 1/n) = M\times\mu(G)$
5. $\mu(f(E)) \leq \mu(f(G)) \leq M\times\mu(G) \leq M\times(\mu(E) + \epsilon)$ for every $\epsilon$.

Does this make sense? Is there a simpler way?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the change of variables formula? That'd do the job quite easily, apply it to the constant function $g=1$. If you don't know it you might still be better of by showing that $f$ is Lipschitz with constant $M$, that is, $|f(x)-f(y)|\le M |x-y|$, which follows from standard theorems about differentiable functions.

Comment: We didn't learn the change of variables formula in this course, so I can't use it, and if I say that $f$ is Lipschitz on $[0,1]$, I still have to show why it follows that $\mu(f(E)) \leq M\times\mu(E)$ for every measurable set $E$...

Comment: I'd try to prove it from the definition of the Lebesgue measure. It's easy to prove that $\mu\big(f(a, b)\big) \leq M*\mu\big((a, b)\big)$; now for any measurable $E$, $\mu\big(f(E)\big)$ is the infimum of the sums over all unions of intervals that cover $f(E)$. Thus, if $\cup (a_i, b_i)$ cover $E$, $f(E)$ is covered by $\cup (c_i, d_i)$ where $\mu(c_i, d_i) \leq M*\mu(a_i, b_i)$.

Comment: Yes, but with the Lipschitz condition it's easier.